# Can't access data through multiple class layers

Tags: c#, class

For my Project I have to build a data structure to represent an xml file.
My Idea was to use multiple classes representing the different xml layers.

My problem now is how can I change data in the lowest layer from the uppermost one.
In my code example are three calls 2 work 1 doesn't. Why doesn't the last one work?

Is there another way of organizing the data?

```
public class option
{
    public string optionID;

    public void setoptionID(string text)
    {
        optionID = text;
    }
}

public class module
{
    public option[] opt = new option[1];
    private string moduleID;

    public void setmoduleID(string text)
    {
        moduleID = text;
    }

}

public class catalogitem
{
    public module[] modul = new module[1];
    private string ShortName;

    public void setShortName(string text)
    {
        ShortName = text;
    }
}

public class Katalog
{
    private catalogitem[] items = new catalogitem[1];

    public Katalog()
    {

    }

    public void setcatalogitems()
    {
        items[0].setShortName("asdf");                  //works
        catalogitem.modul[0].setmoduleID("5");          //works
        items[0].modul[0].setmoduleID("5");             //doesn't work      
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you define 'does not work?' Also, your code does not compile as posted.

Comment: VS 2013 sais that I cant call it by instance but i should call it by typename. (i cant post the complete message because its german)

Comment: It just startet to work. I dont have any idea why.

Comment: Your comments are wrong, catalogitem.modul[0].setmoduleID("5") will show a compile time error as module is not static, it requires an object of catalogitem to get created.......while items[0].modul[0].setmoduleID("5") will not work as modul[0] is still null.......btw, I've provided some suggestions in my answer

Comment: Can you not define your XML object using class files, and then create a utility class with a build XML function utilising the XmlDocument class which will construct an XML object based on your class hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, none of the three statement work.
You have to initialize the objects itself, not only the array.

```
items[0] = new catalogitem();
items[0].setShortName("asdf");      
items[0].modul[0] = new module();
items[0].modul[0].setmoduleID("5");
```

But I would also suggest you, to use properties instead of setShortName() / setmoduleID() in your classes and methods for adding and initializing sub items.

Of course it depends on the specification / your intention (that I don't know), but here is a possible way to implement for example
CatalogItem. You can read/write ShortName and enumerate all existing modules. I would take a list, not an array. Modules can be
only added one by one and you can check them before really adding them:

```
  public class CatalogItem
  {
    private readonly List<Module> mModuls;

    public IEnumerable<Module> Moduls
    {
      get { return mModuls; }
    }

    public string ShortName { get; set; }

    public CatalogItem()
    {
      mModuls = new List<Module>();
    }

    public void AddModule(Module module)
    {
      // Add a check that module is assigned.

      mModuls.Add(module);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions

- Use properties instead of Set Methods
- Write only properties are not good by design
- if you need only one object of a type, create the object instead of array with 1 object
- follow naming conventions [C# Coding Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx) and [Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Your somewhat updated code is below.

```
public class Option
{
    public string OptionID { get; set;}
}

public class Module
{
    // if you need only one Option, why not create one public Option object, instead of an Array
    public Option Option = new Option();
    public string ModuleID { get; set; }
}

public class CatalogItem
{
    public Module Module = new Module();
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
}

public class Katalog
{
    private List<CatalogItem> items = new List<CatalogItem>();

    public Katalog()
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         items.Add(new CatalogItem());
    }

    public void SetCatalogItem()
    {
        foreach(CatalogItem ci in items)
        {
            ci.ShortName = "asdf";
            ci.Module.ModuleID = "5";
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Glad to help! Please remember to accept the answer if you found it helpful.*